# How to select a row from tablelayout using swipe gesture?

Tags: android, swipe, android-tablelayout, gesturedetector

I have a table in my main activity. I am dynamically adding rows to that tablelayout. I want to select a specific row from that tablelayout using swipe gesture. Is it possible? & if so please suggest me some ways to implement. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Refer this one maybe helpful https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss...

Answer (score 0):

Table layout is deprecated at all. Use other methods instead. Otherwise it may get problem.
If you are still using table layout then check this link. It may be help you

[Android TableLayout Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)